# How to get the Text Value of a Clicked Link using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I know it's very easy to get the text value of a link using jQuery.
But Isn't it possible to get the text value using only PHP? Please have a look at my code:

```
echo '<table>'
foreach($array['data']['results']['titles'] as $data) { 

   $title = $data['title'];
   $id= $data['id'];
   $url = $data['url'];

   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . '<a href="movie.php" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>' . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . '<a href= ' .$url . ' target="_blank" >IMDb Link</a>' . '</td>';
   echo '</tr>'; 
}    

echo '</table>';
```

[This picture shows the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lTdB.png)

Suppose the user clicked on the Third movie - Batman: The Animated Series. How do I make my movie.php page look like this -- (image below)

[The Link Text (which is $title) should be passed to the movie.php page and also the IMDb Link of the corresponding movie (which is stored in the $url variable)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLd9v.png)

The Only way I know is using $_SESSION but it won't work in this case as it will only store & pass the last value of the foreach loop

Please help me in this regard. Thanks :)

Comment: Php hasn't got a slightest clue about what is happening on your computer, it's server side. You could potentially do it using $_GET parameters and pass the movie title as href="'.$url.'?movie='.urlencode($movie_title).'", but this approach is just terrible. What you need is to rethink the way you handle data, assign unique ids to the movies and pass them instead of movie names.

Comment: You could pass the value like a `$_GET` like `href="movie.php?n=$title"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering **$id** as the row ID for the particular movie from the Database. You can use url encoding over here. Your code must be

```
echo '<td>' . '<a href="movie.php?id='. urlencode($id) . '" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>' . '</td>';
```

When clicked your URL will look something like.

```
movie.php?id=3
```

On your movie.php file use **$id = urldecode($_GET['id']);** to get the movie ID and you can fetch the relevant data from the DB again.

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: It is not to encrypt or hide your data. This function is to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page. I recommend you to check the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Try sending all info with Proper Primary key OR here is runtime solution

```
echo '<td>' . '<a href="movie.php?name='.$title.'&imdblink='.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>' . '</td>';
```

Don't forget to urlencode the variables

Answer (score 1):

each link should contain the unique filed like `$id` so your url should be `echo '<td>' . '<a href="movie.php?id='.$id.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>' . '</td>';`
You can pass the encoded value of `$id` so end user cannot guess the value.In movie.php you decode the `$id`& show information on the basis of `$id`